# Confluent replicator is unable to replicate data on destination kafka server

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have installed confluent Kafka on two different hosts and trying make confluent replicator work. I have exacted followed whats mentioned in [this tutorial](https://docs.confluent.io/5.1.1/multi-dc-replicator/replicator-quickstart.html#configure-and-run-replicator).

I don't see any errors when I start the replicator and this is the log I see:

> WorkerSourceTask{id=replicator-source-0} Committing offsets
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:397) [2019-03-26
>   06:38:15,049] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=replicator-source-0} flushing 0
>   outstanding messages for offset commit
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:414)

I tried to run the replicator on the both the kafka server hosts; I expect that replicator to replicate data on destination server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake I did was I had source kafka values in connect-standalone.properties. But it should be destination kafka.